# How use one byte buffer as key storage for map?

Tags: go

How use one byte buffer as key storage for map without copy?

```
func TestMap(t *testing.T) {
    testMap := make(map[string]int)

    //byteKey := make([]byte, 2)
    //byteKey[0] = 0
    byteKey := make([]byte, 1)

    {
        byteKey[0] = 'a'
        key := BytesToString(byteKey)
        testMap[key] += 1
    }

    {
        byteKey[0] = 'b'
        key := BytesToString(byteKey)
        testMap[key] += 1
    }

    {
        byteKey[0] = 'c'
        key := BytesToString(byteKey)
        testMap[key] += 1
    }

    for key, _ := range testMap {
        println(key, testMap[key])
    }
}
```

If `BytesToString` is just string cast ( string(buffer) ), that method print:

> a 1
>   b 1
>   c 1

but if `BytesToString` has content:

```
func BytesToString(b []byte) string {
    bytesHeader := (*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&b))
    strHeader := reflect.StringHeader{Data: bytesHeader.Data, Len: bytesHeader.Len}
    return *(*string)(unsafe.Pointer(&strHeader))
}
```

Result of function:

> c 1
>   c 1
>   c 1

Comment: Rule of thumb: Never use package unsafe. Especially if you are not proficient in the language. What you are trying to do is explicitly _forbidden_ by the language. Whatever abomination you are trying to do: Don't.

Comment: @Volker is right, strings are immutable in Go and circumventing this limitation using `unsafe` is highly discouraged. From the looks of your code, you are aware that strings are just a pair of a pointer and length. Since you are pointing to the same memory location, you are using the same key - `byteKey` - for everything. That is why, you are seeing "c" - your last update -as the key for all.

Comment: So hash of key based on address?

Answer (score 2):

> How use [a] ... byte [slice] ... as key ... for map?

You cannot. The language forbids slices as map keys as the content of a slice may change underhand (which is a property no map key must have).